# How can I cancel a Location: header-based page redirect with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, redirect, greasemonkey, dom-events

I have a Greasemonkey script that fixes a rather broken redirect on a web application that I use. However, the behavior of this application has recently changed so that I can no longer use beforescriptexecute for one common case, causing the poorly designed redirect to happen.

This happens with a HTTP 301 status code and a Location header.

I've been digging through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers but have not been able to work out one that can intercept the page before the browser redirects me. Is there any event that fires before the 301 redirect occurs that I can hook onto with Greasemonkey?